# Use one annotation method as default value for other

Tags: java, annotations

```
public @interface MyAnnotation{

    public String someProperty();

    //How should I achieve this?
    public String someOtherProperty() default someProperty();


}
```

I have two properties in the annotation and when one property is not specified then I want to use the other as default value. Is there some way to do this?

Or I have to do following check

```
if(myAnnotation.someOtherProperty() == null){
    //Use the value of someProperty
}
```

Comment: @XaviLópez its not duplicate as this question asks how to use one property as default value for other. The link you gave discusses how to use default values.

Comment: came here hoping for a description of how annotations can be used with _methods_. the link provided does not contain that information.

Answer (score 4):

Your current scenario is simply not possible - the default value of an annotation attribute must be statically resolvable. Right now you are trying to define the default value to be a property that will not be set until the annotation is actually used (aka, dynamically).

What you can do is define your annotation as such:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation{

    public String someProperty();

    public String someOtherProperty() default "";
}
```

Then in your annotation processor, use the value of `someProperty` for `someOtherProperty`, if `someOtherProperty` is blank.